# How to get data in Xamarin C# url with body form-data

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, url, get

Hy Guys,
I'm trying to download data from a url by logging in with a php Web Service but I don't know how to do it.
If I make a POST request via postman inserting in BODY -> form-data the email and password, it gives me this:

{"Users": [{"email": "email@test.it", "nickname": "nickname", "image": "http: \ / \ / localhost \ / MyWebService \ / images \ /test_img.png "}]}

So I created a class in cs like this:

```
public class Users
    {
        [JsonProperty("users", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public User[] UsersUsers { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        [JsonProperty("email", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nickname", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string nickname { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("password", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string password { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("image", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Uri image { get; set; }
    }
```

Instead in the botton function I tried to write this code to contact the Service and make the call :

```
async private void login(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string email = lbl_email.Text;
            string password = lbl_password.Text;
            string url = "http://192.168.178.77/TestLoginURL/api/login.php";


            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email),
              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
            });

            string contentType = "application/json";
            JObject json = new JObject
            {
                { "email", email},
                { "password", password }
            };
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, contentType));
            var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Users>(data);

        }
```

Obviously it is crushed and the error that gives me back is this:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

So, someone can help me?
Where am I wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Have you debugged the value of `data` when you try to deserialize it. Your server may be trying to return a HTML error page  and the serializer would then fail at `<`. Your also not posting `formContent`, just string content is that what you intended? Might explain the error page coming back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in this way :

```
async private void login(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string email = lbl_email.Text;
    string password = lbl_password.Text;
    string url = "http://192.168.178.77/TestLoginURL/api/login.php";

    Users users = new Users();

    FormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email),
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
    });

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

    try
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var responseMessage = client.PostAsync(url, formContent).Result;
        var data = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Users>(data);
        lbl_nickname.Text = users.UsersUsers[0].nickname;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Message.ToString();
        throw;
    }
}
```

The way in which I passed the parameters to the url was practically wrong and consequently it gave me error by not recognizing the email and password I sent.